# C# CSV to Tuple (or useful data type)?

Tags: c#, csv

I work for a school district and we are having to manually create user logins (AD), and GAFE accounts. We would like automate this as much as we can. Currently, We have a CSV file that is exported daily from our SIS (Student information system) that has a list of all new students and I need to read that data, apply some formulas, and output two CSVs, one for GAFE and one for AD, with the results from my formulas.

My thoughts are to read the CSV and save it into a tuple data type, then write a new tuple with the output I need, then save to new CSVs. I thought tuple would work nicely, but I'm still new to C# that I'm not sure what would work best. If you guys have any recommendation on other data types I would love the input.

Here's the header-

```
"SchoolName","firstName","middleName","lastName","grade","studentNumber","Change","startDate","endDate","EnrStartStatus","CalcStartStatus","DateAdded"
"AHS","John","Smith","Doe","12","1779123445","New Student at School","2016-11-29 00:00:00","","","","2016-11-22 20:00:00"
```

So, I'm having some mental logic issues. I'm not sure on how to convert the CSV to tuple without having to do nested foreach loops (the way I'm thinking about going about it doesn't seem efficient.). I figured that there would be a library or something built into C# that would make it so much easier... Any input that is given would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Throdne

Comment: Use an existing CSV library. Don't try to program it yourself.

Comment: @JeffMercado Any recommendation?

Comment: If I were you, I'd make a class that represents a line of your CSV file, and parse the CSV file into a list of instances of that class.

Comment: @SamIam So, you are saying each student (row) would have it's own instance of the class? I was just thinking about the CSV being the only instance of the class. If so, how would I output this to a CSV? (with each row having it's own instance of the class.

Comment: Take a look at [Ctl.Data](https://ctl-global.github.io/data.html).

Comment: @Throdne In memory, yes, it would be ideal to have each row be a class.  Your in-memory representatio of it could be a `List<T>` of your class.  You can use the CSV format for storage on disk or for sending it across a network.  You can theoretically convert back to CSV by iterating over the list of students and writing their values to a new CSV text file., but as Jeff said, it would be best to use a library or tool to do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are several really powerful libraries to most of the work for you.  One really good one is **[CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)** which will not only read and write the data for you, but perform type conversions so that your numbers and dates are stored as numbers and dates.

Given sample data similar to yours:

> "FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","Grade","StudentNumber","EnrollDate"
>   "Ziggy","V.","Aurantium","12","4001809","12/13/2016 6:18:21 PM"
>   "Nancy","W.","Stackhouse","11","9762164","12/15/2016 7:06:20 PM"
>   "Sullivan","N.","Deroche","11","7887589","12/11/2016 1:31:50 PM"

**1. Devise a class for the data**

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollDate { get; set; }

    public Student()
    { }
}
```

**2. Load the Data**

```
// a form/class level collection for the data
List<Student> myStudents;
```

Then to load the data:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\students.csv",  false))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(sr))
{
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csv.Configuration.QuoteAllFields = true;
    myStudents = csv.GetRecords<Student>().ToList();
}
```

That's it: 3 lines of code.  There are many other `Configuration` options to fine tune how it works.  Also:

- If there are a lot of rows, you can leave off the `ToList()` and work with the `IEnumerable` result and load each row as needed
- If the Property names you want to use dont match the CSV header names, you can supply a Map to tell CSVHelper which fields map to which properties.
- Ditto for when there are no field names.
- Exporting your collection to new output CSVs is just as easy as reading them

  - You would also probably need a Map (or two) to control the output order for the output CSVs.

Best of all, it converts the data types for you.  No, wait, best of all is that it wont split up fields with embedded commas (as in `"Ziggy","V.","Aurantium, II","12"...` note the last name data) the way `String.Split(',')` will.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use a string array instead of Tuples.
You can easily convert a line of csv values into a string array with this line of code:

```
    line.Split( new char[] { '"', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

This returns a string array.

Using " and , both as separator characters lets you get rid of the "'s in the same step.

Comment: This is extremely brittle and doesn't handle edge cases in the way a mature library would